# Is it possible to Publicly Query Privately Held Data with proof of Correctness?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation, private-set-intersection, oblivious-ram

We can secretly query inputs from a public DBs using what we call in the literature PIR. We can secretly query inputs from a privately held DB by means of Private Set Intersection (PSI). We can also secretly read/write from a private DB, using ORAM. We can even secretly query a private distributed state, by combining ORAM and MPC.

I wonder, however, what happens for the one use case not annotated above. Let us imagine the Query is public, but the DB is secretly held, how could this be achieved?

What if we take the problem a bit further, a secret distributed state, and a public query. Is there a way to do this? Does it even have a name?

Comment: What do you mean by public query? If it's just a query that is known by the servers maintaining the secret/distributed DB, and your protocol (ORAM/PSI) only supports secret queries, then the servers can just turn the public query into a secret one. Of course, there might be other optimization you can do if the query is public but I think it's easy to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Hi @lamba thanks for your input! Yeah the query would be known by the DB provider. I guess that in the case of ORAM over MPC, something like that could be done.. so you don't reveal anything about the DB to the computing parties holding the state. if its a 2P I  guess at least a proof of correctness would be needed. I wonder if there is any literature about this